# Run Azure CLI Commands from a Azure Function APP

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli, azure-function-app, azureshell

I need suggestions on how to use azure function app to create Web app in Azure under a resource group.
Is there any way from azure function app can i invoke an azure CLI to create a Resource.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Azure function does not support Azure CLI now.At present, there are several Generally available and experimental languages in [`Azure Function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages). You can use Powershell instead.

If you want to create resources using Azure functions, you can use the [REST API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/20/using-the-azure-resource-manager-rest-api/) to create resources and manage them.

Comment: the main idea is to call a azure function app and manage the resources in azure portal i want go with C# but in order to  create or manage a resource in azure whats the idea for it

Comment: @sajeetharan I have a necessity to run a PS script from web API c# code, Isn't that not supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Azure CLI is an executable Python package which you can find it from its PyPI page https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/.

So if you follow the offical tutorial [Quickstart: Create an HTTP triggered Python function in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) to create an Azure Function App for Python, you can try to install Azure CLI as a Python package via `pip install azure-cli`, and then refer to the other SO thread [Azure Function - trigger Python script containing Azure CLI commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405394/azure-function-trigger-python-script-containing-azure-cli-commands/57458509#57458509) to invoke it with your parameters to create a resource as you want.

Of couse, it's not a recommended way to use Azure CLI. May you can make your app works in Python, but the normal solution is to use Azure Management SDK or directly call the related REST API [`Web Apps - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate).

Comment: How do we log in to azure to execute any az commands inside the function app?